# How to bind shortcut to "c-b (maintaining the keys pressed) + j" in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I want to resize panes on Tmux using hjlk instead of the arrows.

The way I'm currently resizing is by maintaining c-b pressed (well, actually c-a), and then using the arrows. I want to do the same with hjkl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these four lines should do what you want:

```
bind  -r k resize-pane -U
bind  -r j resize-pane -D
bind  -r h resize-pane -L
bind  -r l resize-pane -R
```

Comment: That conflicts with my other shortcuts. For example, I can no longer type C-a and then j, as it will execute this shortcut. I want something like the behavior with the arrow keys.

Comment: what do you want?? you cannot expect c-a then j  to do two different thing. If you have already that mapping, you have to choose which function do you want to trigger. @canotto90

Comment: For an example of what I want, take a look at the arrows behavior. If you type C-b, release the keys and the type an arrow key, you will go to another pane. Instead, if you type C-b and, while holding C-b down, you type an arrow key, the pane will get resized. I want the exact same behavior but with hjlk.

Comment: @canotto90 try changing the 4 line, `k` into `c-k`, `j` into `c-j` and so on. see if it works as you expected.

Comment: I didn't work as I expected, but that's because I don't think I can do that. Your answer is as good as this approach can get (I think). I ended up mapping to `bind -n C-J ...`. Thanks!